# Pandas: Assign specific value to a cell of a row based on values from other rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a small dataframe:
[image]

I want to change bad_loan to True if there is at least one row with the same/duplicate ID and its bad_loan is True. For example, the ID 123 repeats 2 times, 1 row has TRUE bad_loan, 1 row has NaN bad_loan. I want to change the duplicated ID with NaN value to TRUE.

So my desired output is a dataframe like this
[image]

I have read multiple solutions but they solved the question on how to assign values based on values from another columns. I am really stuck with my problem. Any ideas for my question? Thank you very much

Comment: `df.groupby('ID')['bad_loan'].transform('max')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about Pandas so maybe my solution is not the most performant, but here's a suggestion:

If your `ID` column is an index, maybe you can play with the fact that `np.NaN`(s) are always considered `<` (less-than) than `True` or even `False` (sort of... a boolean comparison between `NaN` and a boolean will always evaluate to `False`). So the `max` value of (`False` and `NaN`) will be `False` or the `max` value of (`True` and `NaN`) will be `True`.

Let's start with some sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID": [123, 123, 345, 345, 678, 678],
    "bad_loan": [True, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, False, np.NaN],
})
df = df.set_index('ID')
```

You group by `ID`, taking the `.max()` of your `bad_loan` column. This will discard the `NaN`(s) as much as possible:

```
non_nans = df.groupby('ID')['bad_loan'].agg(np.max)
print(non_nans)
# Outputs:
# ID
# 123     True
# 345      NaN
# 678    False
```

Now, you just have to tell pandas to fill up the `NaN`s in your df by taking the values from your `non_nans` series, merging by common index, meaning, by the `ID` column:

```
df = df.fillna({'bad_loan': non_nans})
print(df)
# Outputs:
# ID          
# 123     True
# 123     True
# 345      NaN
# 345      NaN
# 678    False
# 678    False
```

Comment: Very useful information on the fact that np.NaN(s) are always considered < (less-than) than True or even False. Thank you very much. Also, your solution works.

Comment: Sure, though I noticed that I made an inaccurate statement (the solution still works, but my wording is inaccurate). `np.NaN`(s) will always return `False` if you compare them to boolean values. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could mix `fillna()` with a `groupby`:

Start with a df:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [123, np.NaN, True], 
    [123, True, np.NaN], 
    [456, True, np.NaN], 
    [456, np.NaN, np.NaN]
], columns=["ID","good", "bad_loan"]).set_index("ID")


    good    bad_loan
ID      
123 NaN     True
123 True    NaN
456 True    NaN
456 NaN     NaN
```

```py
df['bad_loan'] = df['bad_loan'].fillna(df.groupby('ID')['bad_loan'].transform('max'))
df['good'] = df['good'].fillna(df.groupby('ID')['good'].transform('max'))


    good    bad_loan
ID      
123 True    True
123 True    True
456 True    NaN
456 True    NaN
```